# What size to make common SQL fields?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Fields like username, password, and email for example. Also, in StackOverflow's case, submission details like title, content, tags, etc. Does it make that much of a difference? If anyone is confused by my question, by size I mean how large I make the VARCHAR. Are there set standards for these kinds of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to make any meaningfull assumptions on any kind of data format, especially string lengths and validation rules.

What is a good length for a street address? You might have a very simple address, but other people might have very complex address with a lot of additions (building, room numbers etc). Prematurely optimizing your field lengths may lead to problems for these people and will cause you headaches because changing these limits when your application is live may be very difficult.

To add to this: I suspect that most database will optimize disk usage and communication overhead for you anyway. Look at SQLite, you can supply it with field formats (String, int, etc) but will not actually use them, it will store everything as plain strings. Computing power is so cheap nowadays that these kinds of optimizations are not really usefull (This doesn't hold for *all* optimizations though)

Really, any kind of field validation is quite difficult: when is an email address valid? Now and then you see some silly regex solutions, but these will always have their limits: they will always reject some complex valid cases, and they will always allow fake addresses. The only true way to valid an email address: send a confirmation mail.

So really: if you are planning an application: try to make as little assumptions on field formats as possible.

Comment: No, your first question should be, "Is there a standard?" There is a standard for the length of email addresses. In the US, the USPS sets the standard for street addresses.  (And it's probably longer than you think.)

Comment: True, but when you're on the web, there is more than the US, so considering any standard and think it is globally valid is also a pitfall. (Not that I doubt that the USPS standards are more than thorough enough for your daily use)

Answer (score 1):

They should be specific to your application.

However if you want the standards for personal information (firstname, lastname etc)., you should check out this link:
[Standards](https://www.justice.gov.uk/guidance/docs/electoral-reg-standards.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't really have an application at the moment. I'm just wondering what sites like SO use.

Comment: Also consider UK GovTalk standards e.g. http://interim.cabinetoffice.gov.uk/govtalk/schemasstandards/e-gif/datastandards/person_information/person_name/person_title.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Size is based on your project requirement but the data type should be considered.

If the field is in the range of `char` that should also be declared as `char` not `varchar` that affect your query speed.
You should consider the data type before declaring columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum email address length seems to be 256:

http://www.eph.co.uk/resources/email-address-length-faq/

Is that big enough to hold the other things you mention?

-- pete

Comment: [254](http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail/), actually, per RFC 5321.  The actual string length is 256, but that includes the left and right brackets.